# Horizontal Scrolling in Android home screen widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I have been trying to create an android home screen widget that supports horizontal scrolling.

I put a `GridView` inside the `LinearLayout` of my widget. My `GridView` has some number of columns. I want that at a moment only 5 columns should be visible on the screen and rest should be accessible on scrolling or on click of a button(It should implement a scrolling animation). I used a `HorizontalScrollView` and it said **"Problem Loading Widget"** on my device.

It seems `HorizontalScrollView` is not supported in home screen widgets. Is there another way to implement horizontal scrolling of a `GridView` in android home screen widgets?

Comment: I put a GridView inside the LinearLayout of my widget. My GridView has some number of columns. I want that at a moment only 5 columns should be visible on the screen and rest should be accessible on scrolling. I used a HorizontalScrollView and it said "Problem Loading Widget" on my device.

Comment: Please add your code in the question @user3376390

Comment: Home Screen widgets do not support horizontal scrolling. If they did support it How would you swipe through multiple home pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make app widget scroll horizontally, because this action restricted to switch home screens.

Also you can't use HorizontalScrollView

```
A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

FrameLayout
LinearLayout
RelativeLayout
GridLayout
And the following widget classes:

AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper
Descendants of these classes are not supported.
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make simple Gridview layout with 5 columns you can proceed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add your activity and adapter code.Else if you want to animate the views you can use android gridlayoutmanager with recycler view in material desgin like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle(null);

        Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
        topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));

        List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 4);

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
    }
private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.one));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.two));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.three));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.four));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.five));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.six));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.seven));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.eight));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.one));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.two));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.three));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.four));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.five));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.six));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.seven));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.eight));

        return allItems;
    }
    }
```